# Textbox Array does not update in userControl WIndows Forms

Tags: c#, textbox, user-controls

I wonder if someone can help me with this.

I am attempting to build a User Control with a collection of TextBoxes. The idea is to be able to display a collection of information.

I can get a single Textbox to update, but I just can't get an array to do the same thing.

The function _aTextBox() is called from 2 buttons on my main program as follows:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
 ucTextBox1._aTextBox("Hello");  
}  
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    ucTextBox1._aTextBox("World");  
}
```

`My User Control code is below:`

```
Namespace ucTextBox  
{  
public partial class ucTextBox: UserControl  
{  
public ucTextBox()  
  {  
                 InitializeComponent();  
  }  
                 TextBox[] txt = new TextBox[2];  
private void DisplayTextBoxes()  
  {  
     txt[0] = new TextBox();  
     txt[0].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20, 48);  
     this.Controls.Add(txt[0]);  
  }  
public void _aTextBox(string text)  
   {  
     DisplayTextBoxes();  
     txt[0].Visible = false;  
     txt[0].Text = text; // *********************  
     txt[0].Visible = true;  
     txt[0].Invalidate();  
     txt[0].Update();  
     txtValue.Visible = true;  
     txtValue.Text = text;  
     txt[0].ResumeLayout(true);  
    }  
  }  
}
```

*At the line marked with // *********************, txt[0].Text holds the correct string. However, it never displays it!!!*

Any and all suggestions welcomed . Many thanks for your time reading this.

John

Answer (score 0):

I think you are drawing all textboxes at the same location. you have to sum something with the x and y coordinates.

the last drawn textbox is the top one and hides the first inserted one.

Answer (score 0):

since every time you call _aTextBox(string text)
that function calls DisplayTextBoxes();
where you always rewrite your txt[0] with new TextBox();
May be you will want to use an List instead of Array and add textboxes to the end of it.